# What are subsurface modifiers?

Tags: modifiers, terminology

Using version 2.78c, hash e92f235283. Following instructions in "Beginning Bender" by Flavell, 2010. I have opened Modifiers, but have not found any modifiers referred to as subsurface modifiers.

Comment: Maybe you mean subdivision surface modifier (aka subsurf modifier)?

Answer (score 3):

From the Blender Docs:
*The Subdivision Surface Modifier is used to split the faces of a mesh into smaller faces giving a smooth appearance..*...

For more info, visit the documentation:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html